# Remove space between screen end and table start

Tags: android, user-interface, android-tablelayout

I'm programmatically creating table layout so I can't do this with XML but have to do it with code. I have tables. But the distance from the side of the screen to the tables is too big. Is Android doing this on it's own? Is there a way to change it?

These here are my LayoutParams for the table

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams        = new TableLayout   .LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);                      
tableLayout.setPadding(1,0,0,1);
tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
ll.addView(tableLayout)
```

So basically nothing special. How Can I change it that it is closer.
For the padding I used

Left: 1px, Top: 0px, Right: 1px, Bottom: 1px.

So basically I don't know what to do to make it more width. Any suggestions?
So basically I just want that my table is as width as the screen width. Or just some pixels smaller. Any ideas how I can achieve this? At the moment its too far away

Comment: You should also change the padding on the LinearLayout, and the margin on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding is the interior space. You'll need to check/remove the padding on the LinearLayout that contains the TableLayout also.

If that doesn't do it completely, check/adjust the `margin` on both layouts as well.